# couldn't invoke virtual function of an object from a global function

Tags: c++, cuda

In this simple CUDA program, I have a struct `Foo` and another struct `Bar` that inheritans from it. `Foo` implements `print()` that can be used in a global function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// limited version of checkCudaErrors from helper_cuda.h in CUDA examples
#define checkCudaErrors(val) check_cuda((val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void check_cuda(cudaError_t result, char const *const func, const char *const file, int const line) {
    if (result) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA error = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(result) << " at " << file << ":" << line << " '"
             << func << "' \n";
        // Make sure we call CUDA Device Reset before exiting
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(-1);
    }
}

struct Foo {
    __host__ __device__ void print() const {
        printf("Foo: print()\n");
    }
};

struct Bar: Foo {};

__global__
void test(const Foo* foo) {
    foo->print();
}

int main()
{
    Foo * cpu_bar;
    cpu_bar = new Bar();

    Foo * gpu_bar;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&gpu_bar, sizeof(Foo)));

    cudaMemcpy(gpu_bar, cpu_bar, sizeof(Foo), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    test<<<2,3>>>(gpu_bar);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    return 0;
}
```

Things are working well until I change `Foo::print()` to virtual function:

```cpp
    __host__ __device__ virtual void print() const {
        printf("Foo: print()\n");
    }
```

Now I have `CUDA error 700` calling function `test<<<2,3>>>(gpu_bar);`

How do I fix this bug?

Comment: `cudaMalloc(&gpu_bar, sizeof(Foo))`? Shouldn't that be `sizeof(Bar)`?

Comment: It illegal to pass functions with virtual members from host to device. A host instantiated class will have a vtable of host function pointers which are invalid on the GPU